# divide data into subgroups

Tags: sql, teradata

I have y=20 rows and would like to create a new column which divides the rows into n subgroups. Let us say n is 4 the result would be:

```
RowNumber   NewColumn
1   1
2   1
3   1
4   1
5   1
6   2
7   2
8   2
9   2
10  2
11  3
12  3
13  3
14  3
15  3
16  4
17  4
18  4
19  4
20  4
```

How could I achieve this in SQL/TeraData please?

PS:

To add to the accepted answer, I am using something along those lines:

```
1 + FLOOR((ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY Id DESC ) - 1) / 100) AS SubGroup
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can just use arithmetic:

```
select 1 + floor((row_number - 1) / 4) as newColumn
from t;
```

Note:  Teradata prefers to be integer division, so `floor()` is not strictly necessary.

Answer (score 1):

There's an old function to bucket data into percentiles, [QUANTILE](http://www.info.teradata.com/HTMLPubs/DB_TTU_13_10/index.html#page/SQL_Reference/B035_1145_109A/ch09.13.122.html), but it's deprecated:

```
QUANTILE(4, ORDER BY whatever ASC)
```

When you already use another OLAP-function you better rewrite it to

```
4 * (RANK() OVER (ORDER BY whatever) - 1) 
/ COUNT(*) OVER()
```

Both return a value between 0 and n, so you have to add 1 to get your expected result.

Btw, in Standard SQL there's `NTILE` which return a slightly different result, see [Missing Functions: CUME_DIST & NTILE](https://downloads.teradata.com/blog/dnoeth/2011/05/missing-functions-cume-dist-ntile)